# marker manager and circle object

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have to prepare map with ~30k circle objects which is quite a challenge on G Maps.

While looking for solution I stumbled upon marker manager as a way to reduce displayed objects to certain zoom level.

Is it possible to use marker manager to circle objects instead of markers?

Answer (score 0):

Both the [marker manager](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markermanager/) and (probably better) the [marker clusterer](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/) are open source.  You can modify one of them to manage circles rather than markers (or use markers that are circles).

[Too many markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#markermanager) article from the documentation discussed the issues if you haven't seen it.